# If $xy+yz+zx=1$ , show that $\dfrac x{1-x^2}+\dfrac y{1-y^2}+\dfrac z{1-z^2}=\dfrac{4xyz}{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)(1-z^2)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It is to be solved using trigonometry. I tried taking $x$, $y$ and $z$ as $\sin(a)$, $\sin(b)$ and $\sin(c)$ respectively, but could get no further.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\tan A, y = \tan B, z = \tan C$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\tan(A+B+C) = \frac{\tan A + \tan B + \tan C - \tan A \tan B \tan C}{1-\tan A \tan B -\tan B \tan  C-\tan C \tan A} 
\end{align*}
Hence $A+B+C $ is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. We need to prove
\begin{align*}
\tan 2A + \tan 2B + \tan 2C  = \tan 2A \tan 2B \tan 2C
\end{align*}
This is clear since $2A + 2B + 2C$ is a multiple of $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

$$x(1 - y^2)(1 - z^2) + y(1 - x^2)(1 - z^2) + z(1 - x^2)(1 - y^2)$$
$$=$$
$$x - xy^2 - xz^2 + xy^2z^2 + y - yx^2 - yz^2 + yx^2z^2 + z - zx^2 - zy^2 + zx^2y^2$$
$$=$$
$$(x + y + z)\cdot 1 - xy^2 - xz^2  - yx^2 - yz^2 - zx^2 - zy^2 + \frac{xy^2z^2 + yx^2z^2 + zx^2y^2}{1}$$
$$=$$
$$4xyz$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't know if x,y and z are between -1 and +1.Take them as tan(a),tan(b),tan(c) and use tana.tanb + tanb.tanc + tana.tanc=1